# PostgreSQL database reverse engineering from shell level

Tags: postgresql, reverse-engineering

I happened to do some moderating stuff with large database but I am not so experienced in it so i guess the smart thing is to create similar database on my localhost to not mess up with original one.
And here is my question, is it possible to generete `SQL` script which will create exact table as i want?
 I mean on MySQL GUI tool there is option like this, `reverse engineering` which generate `SQL` script which will create exact database as I used function on, is it possible in PostgreSQL in shell level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pg_dump --schema-only db1 > db-schema.sql
```

Comment: does it not takes records saved with it? Is it possible to use it somehow only on tables with out records? edit: ahh ok `--schema-only` i get it. Thank you Richard.

Comment: That is what --schema-only does. Read the manual for full details http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html